# Regex - IIS URL rewrite pagination

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

My URL looks like this:

```
domain.com/12345/some-product-category
```

and with the optional pagination:

```
domain.com/12345-2/some-product-category
```

so far my pattern looks like this:

```
^([0-9]{5})(-[0-9]+)?/([_0-9a-z-]*)
```

but the capture {R:2} return "-2" and not "2" as wanted... How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an expression like this:

```
^(\d{5})(?:-(\d+))?/([\w-]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

because you've placed in your group `-[0-9]+` and not `[0-9]+`. You should take off minus sign from group.
Try this regex `^([0-9]{5})(-([0-9]+))?/([_0-9a-z-]*)` and take group 3.

Comment: The "-" is also optinal together with the pagination number. The above will fail.